# The Shade Smooth option is ignored when baking a displacement map

Tags: texture-baking, baking

[image]

Is the smoothing option meaningless since the displacement map is meant to be extracted from high polygons?

So what is the correct way to create a greyscale bump map?

And here is my blend file

[image]

Comment: can you detail how exactly are you baking from 1 to 2?

Comment: Well ... I baked the sphere to the plane to get a dome-shaped bump map. So I do not have to overlap two spheres. The reason for capturing the two spheres is to show you that the blender ignores the shade smooth option when baking works. I modified the attached image to help you understand.

Comment: I mean, which render engine? which kind of bake, how can I reproduce exactly? can you share the file (use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then paste the provided link text iediting your question)? Anyway I guess yuor bake reflects object geometry, and shading doesn't alter that.

Comment: I apologize for posting duplicate questions. I made my question more clear. And I attached the blend file according to your advice. I baked it in BI and then rendered it in Cycles. Could you check my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's much more clear and you put your "real" question.

It seems you wish to bake **displacement** (ie: geometry) from **shading** (ie lighting): it will never work imho.

Use a real "smoothing" option, like more subsurf

[image]

so, why "Shade Smooth" doesn't work when baking a displacement map, unlike the "normal map" (that works)?

because "smooth shading" is, in fact, just a shading trick: it alters the **normals**, to let the object appear smooth (as if it had more geometry, which it has not), so the **normal baking** takes it into account.

the "displacement baking" instead needs to bake the geometry "height levels" into color levels (the baked image), but since "smooth shading" leaves the **geometry** untouched, you get the same identical result as without the smooth shading...

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice solution.
But I'm studying the theory now, so I wonder why Shade Smooth doesn't work when baking a displacement map, unlike the normal map.
My guess is that shade smoothing is meaningless because a single polygon has a size of less than 1 pixel on the image to be baked, because the original displacement map baking feature was intended to be extracted from the high polygon model. Am I making the right guess?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain why (imho)...